# ASP.NET IIS 6 deployment error - Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I am working on an ASP.NET website. I am trying to deploy the website on Windows 2003 server, IIS 6.  The website works fine when I run using Visual studio 2010. but I am not able to deploy on IIS 6 and access the website login page.

I published the website and created a new Virtual directory in IIS 6 pointing to the precompiled website folder under c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\App-name folder.

I get the below error message when i try to access the website login page.

The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.

---

A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource 
'http://myappservr.com/app-name/Login.aspx'. Line 1, Po...

<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="Login, App_Web_rmgltjnq" %>
-^

In IIS, under ASP.NET tab, I selected the ASP.NET version as v2.0.   In IIS, under Web service extensions folder ASP.NET 2.0 is allowed.

Why the does the browser show the message is The XML page cannot be displayed Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet  when I access the aspx page from the IIS?

Please let me know how to fix this issue when access the website from IIS 6.0

Thanks
Ashok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving means that IIS is not processing the asp.net pages at all. It is simply displaying the HTML directly to the browser. The error you are getting is the same one you would receive if you opened the .aspx page directly in the browser from the file system.

Steps to make sure

1. the .net framework is actually installed on the server.
2. if it is, make sure it is enabled to be served. MS disabled many application development features by default to avoid servers becoming a potential viral attack vector.

   Go to the Server Manager on the server

   Select the Web Server (IIS) Role to show the details under the Role Services list ensure that the Web Server | Application Development | ASP.Net and .Net Extensibility nodes are Installed.

   If not, select the Add Role Services options to add those and any other Application Development eatures you need.
3. If correct, you may need to run [aspnet_regiis to update the mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Usually the -i or -ir options are most commonly selected.